# Inflate layout and use its child items

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I have a layout where I want to imitate a listview by adding items programmatically one below the other. So I created an .xml for the layout of these items that are something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/ll_lista"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
      android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rellay_btn"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/tv_username"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
          android:text="Some name"
          android:textColor="#3F3F3F"
          android:textSize="17sp"
          android:textStyle="bold" />


      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/tv_tip"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@+id/iv_follow"
          android:text="Some text"
          android:textColor="#3F3F3F"
          android:textSize="13sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In the activity I would like to generate n of this layout, fill the textviews with text and also I would like to set an onClickListener on them. n is the size of an array. Please help

Note: Once the activity loads, the number of layouts will not change, nor can a layout be removed.

This is what I have now but the layout is displayed on top of the activity instead of below a Textview:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(BucketProfileActivity.this);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bucketprofile_tips, null);
    view.setId(i);
    TextView tv_username = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_username);
    tv_username.setText(String.valueOf(i));
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rl = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    rl.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.tv_nemkell);
    addContentView(view, rl);
}
```

Comment: Just wondering, but why would using a ListView not suffice?

Comment: Because it's a fairly complex layout in a scrollview

Comment: Can you not just use `LayoutInflater.inflate()` in a for loop the number of times desired. Initialize\set up each layout and add them to the desired view?

Comment: Is your posted xml file is bucketprofile_tips.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to do this but you can just use a `LayoutInflater` to inflate x of this view and add them to a designated `ViewGroup`. For example:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_to_add, parentView, false);
    setup(v);
    parentView.addView(v);
}
```

Where `setup()` is a function you define that does the setup work such as setting the text of a  `TextView` etc.

For instance, in your setup function might look something like this:

```
private void setup(View v) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
    // set the text of the text view
    tv.setText("Hello!");

    // set the click listener for the view...
    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do stuff here...
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I still have no idea how to what I want. What is parentView? How do I set an onclicklistener on the views?

Comment: `parentView` is the `ViewGroup` you want to add your views to. This is normally a `LinearLayout`. I've updated the answer to show an example of how you would set the `OnClickListener` of the view.

Answer (score 0):

If your posted xml file is `bucketprofile_tips.xml` then you need to change here from

```
TextView tv_username = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
```

to

```
TextView tv_username = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_username);
```

Because in `bucketprofile_tips.xml` `tv_title` id not found for your `TextView`. So you are getting `Null Pointer Exception`.

Comment: That was just a mistake, there is a tv_username in the xml and this answer is not solution to my question

Comment: Try to change this from LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(BucketProfileActivity.this); to LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater(); and I have already specified in my first line for this solution.

Comment: Thanks for the help but that is not the case. Please see my updated post.

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout parentLayout=findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(BucketProfileActivity.this);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bucketprofile_tips, null);
parentLayout.addView(view);
LinearLayout textList=(LinearLayout) parentLayout.getChildAt(0);
for(int i=0; i<textList.getChildCount(); i++){
    TextView tv_username=(TextView) textList.getChildAt(i);
    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            tv_username.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        }
    }
}
```